# Create multiple records in relationship table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I have a model driven powerapp and the following scenario where I need to be able to create multiple records in a relationship table, ideally without a create form.

I have a table "Faults", and another table "Assets", and a relationship table "Fault Assets" which just has two columns which relate to a Fault and an Asset.

On the Fault form I have a Fault Assets subgrid where these records are displayed and can be created, but this can only be done one at a time (using the Fault Assets form which only has one field; a lookup to the Asset table).

What I need is to be able to select multiple Assets and add them to the Fault Asset table in one go. How can I approach this? Do I need to embed a canvas app onto the form, or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up creating my own custom dataset component using [PowerApps Component Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/overview). This took a bit of understanding (there is a decent MS Learn course on it) and some digging into other users code looking at the [PCF Gallery](https://pcf.gallery/) to wrap my head around how to implement it, but I got it working in the end.